# How to run blazor wasm in jetbrains rider

Tags: rider, blazor-webassembly

I am using latest MacOS and latest version of Rider.
Seeking advise on how to set up build configuration for a hosted blazor wasm project. Created with this command:

```
dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted -o blazorhosted
```

I cd into blazorhosted/server and execute

```
dotnet run watch
```

and everything works as expected.
But I don't know how to run it in Rider. As a side not also works in VS Code with debugging on client and server.

This is the error I am getting when running the server configuration in Rider

```
    Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.StaticWebAssets.targets(184, 5): Duplicate base  paths '/' 
    for content root paths '/Users/mha/projects/blazorhosted/Client/bin/Debug/netstandard2.1/wwwroot/' 
    and '/Users/mha/projects/blazorhosted/Client/wwwroot/'. 
    ('/Users/mha/projects/blazorhosted/Client/obj/Debug/netstandard2.1/blazor/unlinked/blazorhosted.Client.dll',
     '/Users/mha/projects/blazorhosted/Client/wwwroot/css/app.css')
```

Comment: Any solution to this? I have a Blazor Wasm project that runs in VS on Windows but cannot get it to run in Rider on Linux.

Comment: The Rider docs says it's only working on windows.